# Azure AD Open ID Connect OAuth 2.0 in ASP.NET Web APP and Web API Infinite redirect loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, cookies, openid-connect

ASP.NET web app to sign in personal accounts and work and school accounts from any Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) instance.

**OWIN middleware NuGet packages**

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
```

**OWIN Startup Class**
   The OWIN middleware uses a startup class that runs when the hosting process initializes. In this quickstart, the startup.cs file located in the root folder. The following code shows the parameter used by this quickstart

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
            // ResponseType is set to request the id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
            // ValidateIssuer set to false to allow personal and work accounts from any organization to sign in to your application
            // To only allow users from a single organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and 'tenant' setting in web.config to the tenant name
            // To allow users from only a list of specific organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and use ValidIssuers parameter
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false // Simplification (see note below)
            },
            // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
            }
        }
    );
}
```

**ASP.NET MVC / Web API**

```
//You can force a user to sign in by requesting an authentication challenge in your controller:
public void SignIn()
{
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties{ RedirectUri = "/" },
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }
}
```

**ASP.NET Web Form:**

```
 protected void Login_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has been fixed in ASP.NET core and in the new version of Katana Owin for ASP.NET.  To resolve this issue, you can upgrade your application to use ASP.NET Core. If you must continue stay on ASP.NET, perform the following:

Update your application’s Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb package be at least version 3.1.0.0 and
Modify your code to use one of the new cookie manager classes, for example something like the following:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions 
{ 
    AuthenticationType = "Cookies", 
    CookieManager = new Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.SystemWebChunkingCookieManager() 
});
```